# Переименовать файлы по ссылке PHP

Tags: php

Есть массив со ссылками на файлы с одинаковым именем. Как переименовать default.htm 
в index.php?

```
array(127) {
  [0]=>
  string(77) "D:\OpenServer\OSPanel\domains\stroika.to/otchety/izumrudnye-holmy/default.htm"
  [1]=>
  string(109) "D:\OpenServer\OSPanel\domains\stroika.to/otchety/otcht-s-primki-kvartiry-v-zhk-chernyahovskogo-19/default.htm"
  [2]=>
  string(101) "D:\OpenServer\OSPanel\domains\stroika.to/otchety/otcht-s-primki-kvartiry-v-zhk-mayakovsij/default.htm"
  [3]=>
  string(105) "D:\OpenServer\OSPanel\domains\stroika.to/otchety/otcht-s-primki-kvartiry-v-zhk-salar-evo-park/default.htm"
}
```

ссылки на файлы в разных папках

Comment: Пробегись форичем и [переименуй](http://www.php.su/functions/?rename) . Что конкретно не получается?

Comment: Подскажите как это сделать правильною Сейчас просто вывожу список  ссылок для наглядностию

Comment: foreach ($found as $link) {
    echo '<pre>';
    echo $link;
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach ($found as $link) { 
   rename($link, str_replace('default.htm', 'index.php', $link)); 
}
```

Но я не уверен, что с такими путями будет работать. Если не будет то можно будет дополнительно обработать линки регуляркой